Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) IMAGES
I'm creating a web application using node.js, react.js and mongodb. I'm currently uploading files and wanting to display them (images/files).
The upload works well but the display always shows me this error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Backend code:
const uploadsPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'../app/uploads')
app.use(express.static(uploadsPath));

// Set up multer for handling file uploads
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(_req, _file, cb) {
    cb(null, uploadsPath);
  },
  filename(_req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, `${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`);
  },
});

app.post('/upload-file', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.file) {
    return res.status(400).send('No file uploaded.');
  }

  const fileName = req.file.filename;

  const dbInstance = client.db(db);
  const collection = dbInstance.collection('files');

  try {
    await collection.insertOne({ file: fileName });
    return res.json({ status: 'ok', filename: fileName });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ status: 'error', message: error.message });
  }
});
app.get('/get-file', async (req, res) => {
  const dbInstance = client.db(db);
  const collection = dbInstance.collection('files');

  try {
    const files = await collection.find({}).toArray();
    res.json({ status: 'ok', data: files });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ status: 'error', message: error.message });
  }
});

Frontend code:
  useEffect(() => {
    getImage();
  }, []);
  //UPLOAD FILES
  const submitImage = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);

    try {
      const token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
      console.log(token);

      const response = await fetch(`/upload-file`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          
        },
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to upload file");
      }

      setUploadSuccess(true); // Set success state to true

      // Refresh images after successful upload
      getImage();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading file:", error);
    }
  };

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  //get image
  const getImage = async () => {
    try {
      const token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
      console.log(token);

      const response = await fetch(`/get-file`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch images");
      }
      const result = await response.json();

      setAllImage(result.data);
      console.log(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching images:", error);
    }
  };

I tried to change access permissions to the upload file:

Nothing ever changed.

What are you using for Authorization ?
Do you have a middleware that checks authorization ?
I ask because Frontend is passing an Authorization header
